# Has the satisfiability of the following horn expressions correctly been determined? [verification]

Tags: proof-verification, logic, propositional-calculus, satisfiability

I have the following task

"Check the following expressions with the horn satisfiability algorithm, and, if necessary, provide an assignment which fulfills satisfiability."

1. $((\neg q \lor \neg p) \land (\neg r \lor p) \land \neg q \land \neg r)$
2. $((\neg q \lor p) \land (\neg r \lor p) \land q \land r)$
3. $((\neg q \lor \neg p) \land (\neg r \lor p) \land q \land r )$

---

Progress so far:

I have been provided with the following algorithm:

"
a) For each implication of the form $\top \to B$, assign True to $B$.

b) If for an implication of the form $(A_1 \land \dots \land A_n) \to B$ the atomic sentences $A_1, \dots, A_n$ have already been assigned True, then assign true to B aswell.

c) Repeat step b as much as possible.

d) If the following result is reached $(A_1 \land \dots \land A_n) \to \perp$, and all atomic sentences $A_1, \dots, A_n$ have been assigned true, then S is not truth table satisfiable.  Otherwise, for all atomic sentences from S which have not yet been assigned a value, assign them the value False. The assignment thus obtained makes S true."

---

My problem is that it is not intuitive to me how the verum and falsum symbols are used in the first place. I am aware that $a \to b \equiv \neg a \lor b$, and that this is a key property of horn expressions, but that's about it. Could someone help me make a start on one of above examples so I check my understanding with the other two?

---

further progress:

As has been proposed, a good starting point would be to write the formula as a set of implications. In order to do this step, I found a [Youtube video in German](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lWSGFWBCYr8) which indicates the necessary transformations by use of colour coding.

Step $0$: Implication form.

1) $((\neg q \lor \neg p) \land (\neg r \lor p) \land \neg q \land \neg r) \equiv (((q \land r) \to \perp) \land (r \to p) \land (q \to \perp) \land (r \to \perp))$

2) $((\neg q \lor p) \land (\neg r \lor p) \land q \land r) \equiv ((q \to p) \land (r \to p) \land (\top \to q) \land (\top \to r))$

3) $((\neg q \lor \neg p) \land (\neg r \lor p) \land q \land r ) \equiv (((q \land p) \to \perp) \land (r \to p) \land (\top \to q) \land (\top \to r))$

step $1$: Apply the algorithm.

**part 1**) $((q \to p) \land (r \to p) \land (\top \to q) \land (\top \to r))$

a) Not applicable here.

b) & c) There are no sentences in this form, so also not applicable here.

d) Assign the value $\perp$ to $q$ and $r$.

At this point $p$ in $(r \to p)$ is the only variable which hasn't been assigned a value. As it appears, it can be assigned any value and the expression will eb true.

Thus, I would conclude that part 1 is truth table satisfiable and propose the **solution for part 1** as 
$q = \perp, r = \perp, r = \perp$ OR $q = \perp, r = \perp, r = \top$

**part 2**) $((q \to p) \land (r \to p) \land (\top \to q) \land (\top \to r))$

a) Assign the value $\top$ to $q$ and $r$..

b) and c) the value $\top$ to $p$

Thus, I would conclude that part 1 is truth table satisfiable I would propose the **solution for part 2** as $q = \top, r = \top, r = \top$.

**part 3**) $(((q \land p) \to \perp) \land (r \to p) \land (\top \to q) \land (\top \to r))$

a) Assign $\top$ to $q$ and $r$

b) and c) Assign $\top$ to $p$

d) Since the above assignment furnishes the result $(q = \top \land p = \top) \to \perp$, the expression is not satisfiable.

**Solution for part 3**: The expression is not satisfiable (and no truth value assignment is provided)

Comment: Are you also aware that $(A_1\land\dots\land A_n)\implies B$ (which occurs in the algorithm) is equivalent to $(\neg A_1)\lor\dots\lor(\neg A_n)\lor B$, a Horn clause?

Comment: That makes sense to me, but Horn clauses are a new topic for me, so even if knowing that is a large hint, at the very least I would need to think about how I can use that piece of information.

Comment: That was my intention --- to bridge the notation gap between the question and the algorithm, so that you can start thinking seriously about the essential (rather than the notational) issues. That's why I wrote only a comment, not an answer.

Comment: I understand, thanks for helping get things moving. To think out loud, the Horn clause is a disjunction of literals. In another of my [posts](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2832451/prove-that-a-sentence-is-a-tautology-using-resolution), I was shown how to determine the satisfiability of a disjunction of literals by using the resolution technique. What do you think about using this technique in order to derive the tautology symbol which appears in the above algorithm? Also, I seem to recall another technique for this kind of problem, but at the time I couldn't understand the tutorial.

Comment: First, you should rewrite the formula you want to test as a set of implications, since the algorithm is given in terms of implications. After that, you could just run the algorithm by hand, pretending that you're a machine. But I guess (and hope) that you want not only to run the algorithm but to understand how and why it works. That might become evident while you run an example or two, but I'll give a hint: Steps 1 and 2 gradually build up information of the form "such-and-such variable absolutely must get the value true if the formulas are to be satisfied."

Comment: Hi @AndreasBlass I have had a bit of a think and tried to solve the problem myself. I would be grateful for any criticism/feedback you could provide. 

Also, I would like to understand how and why the algorithm works. If you have any literature you might recommend, I would be grateful for that too.